# Appending a 2D array to another 2D array, gets inserted as a single row instead

Tags: javascript, arrays, append, splice

I'm having problems to append a 2D array at the end of another 2D array.

The first array called array_from_sheet I construct from reading a range of cells in Google sheet, from a range of 5 columns and 100 rows. This first array looks like this in debug window:
[["2017-12-02T16:49:48.9Z", 1040036, 399.07, 0.01, "sell"], ["2017-12-02T16:49:48.9Z", 1040037, 399.08, 1.12907707, "sell"], [....

The second array called trades comes from a JSON string that i parsed and looks like this in debug window (it has 100 rows and 5 columns):
[["2017-12-02T18:06:55.909Z", 1040574, "399.00000000", "1.12619681", "sell"], ["2017-12-02T18:06:55.829Z", 1040573, "399.00000000", "1.31054161", "sell"], [...

this is before my splice command: trades.splice(1, 0, array_from_sheet);

After my splice command, the trades array looks like this in debug window:
[["2017-12-02T18:06:55.909Z", 1040574, "399.00000000", "1.12619681", "sell"], [["2017-12-02T16:49:48.9Z", 1040036, 399.07, 0.01, "sell"], [...

You can see the second row now starts with a double bracket, problem i guess.

The debug window says it has now 101 rows while it should have 200. The second row of the new array now has 100 elements into it, looks like array_from_sheet got inserted here instead on the same row.

(I tried the .push command but got same problem)

(array_from_sheet.length returns 100, so it appears to be 100 rows)

Here's my code:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var first = ss.getSheetByName("trades");
  first.activate();  

  //var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('DEV_GDAX Order book and trades')
  //var APIPullSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("APIPull");
  //first.getRange('A2:D19999').clearContent();

  // call the trades from GDAX into var parcedData- should add error handling here if server does not respond or return error code
  var url = "https://api.gdax.com/products/ETH-EUR/trades"
  var responseAPI = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)
  var parcedData = JSON.parse(responseAPI.getContentText());

  // creates new empty array trades, adds headers on first row, 
  var trades = new Array ();
  //trades.push(['time', 'trade_id', 'price', 'size','side'])   hll: i removed this line as i don't need headers, i have them on row1 in sheet

  // create temp array for a row, read from parsedData, push to temp, repeat, then push to temp (more or less)
  var keys = ['time', 'trade_id', 'price', 'size','side'];
  for (var i in parcedData) {
    var temp = [];
    for (var j in keys) {
       temp.push(parcedData[i][keys[j]]);
    }
    trades.push(temp);
    //Logger.log(trades)
  }


  //here i should remove duplicates first before coyping to sheet trades
  //load current trades on sheet in temp array
  var lastRow = first.getLastRow();
  var array_from_sheet = first.getRange('A2:E' + lastRow).getValues();
  Logger.log("array-from-sheet: ");
  Logger.log(array_from_sheet);

  //append new trades array to array_from_sheet
  trades.splice(1, 0, array_from_sheet);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

I used this command:

trades_new = array_from_sheet.concat(trades);

instead of:

trades.splice(1, 0, array_from_sheet);

now trades_new contains the 2 arrays end to end.